# Finding greatest length in set by comparing indexes

Tags: java

I am trying to make a program in java that finds the greatest length between any pair of coordinates in the entire set through comparison.

I suppose my problem is less about finding the max length and more about creating all possible pairings. I don't really understand what I am supposed to put in place for x and y coordinates in the given equation. How would I get the coordinates from each pair and compare them? I've read duplicate solutions but I'm fairly new to programming and I couldn't understand them.

This is the part of my code that I have so far that's relevant to this problem:

```
public static void main (String[] args) {
    int[][] countries = {{-34,-7},{76,-23},{-5,-20},{-56,64},{12,56}};

double maxDistance = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < countries.length-1; ++i) {
      for(int j = i; j < countries.length; ++j) {
        double distance = Math.sqrt((x1-x2)*(x1-x2) + (y1-y2)*(y1-y2));
```

I would appreciate any help or even a push in the right direction.

I'm confused as to how I would define my x/y variables because I'm just pulling coordinates from the countries array so I thought they were already defined? I was thinking there would be a way to compare indexes or something in the equation.

THANK YOU BOTH SO MUCH!

Comment: start your j from i i.e. for(int j=i; j<countries.length; ++j).. because you have already compared previous indexes with the rest of the array. And, did you define your x1, x2, y1, y2 variables?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I change a bit on your code

```
int[][] countries = { { -34, -7 }, { 76, -23 }, { -5, -20 }, { -56, 64 }, { 12, 56 } };

double maxDistance = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < countries.length - 1; ++i) {
    int x1 = countries[i][0];
    int y1 = countries[i][1];
    for (int j = i; j < countries.length; ++j) { // first j will be i
        int x2 = countries[j][0];
        int y2 = countries[j][1];
        double distance = Math.sqrt((x1 - x2) * (x1 - x2) + (y1 - y2) * (y1 - y2));
        maxDistance = maxDistance < distance ? distance : maxDistance;
    }
}
System.out.println(maxDistance);
```

Output

> 158.09174551506476

notice how I loop `i` and `j`, and how i define `x1, x2, y1, y2`

Answer (score 2):

start your j after i because you have already compared previous indexes with the rest of the array. And, did you define your x1, x2, y1, y2 variables?

This should help:

```
int[][] countries = {{-34,-7},{76,-23},{-5,-20},{-56,64},{12,56}};

double maxDistance = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < countries.length-1; ++i) {
      for(int j = i+1; j < countries.length; ++j) { //do not create zero distance or duplicate pairings
        //get your x1, x2, y1, y2 from countries[i] and countries[j]
        double distance = Math.sqrt((x1-x2)*(x1-x2) + (y1-y2)*(y1-y2));
        //compare with maxDistance
        //assign maxDistance if you find it greater than previous one and record the coordinates which produced this distance
    }
}
```

Leave a comment if something is not clear or if I missed something ;)